# When to split a database table instead of adding more columns - Performance - Database Design

Tags: sql-server, performance, database-design, split

The question is add more columns or split database table.

Assume that I have a table which keeps:

```
UserId - Primary Key
Col1
Col2
Col3
```

Now I will keep another data as Col4 Col5,
but this data won't be valid for every UserId.

Let's say there are 2 million records at my main table and this additional data will be valid for only 25000 records. So the question is: should I compose another table as

```
UserId - Primary Key
Col4
Col5
```

or

use my main table as

```
UserId - Primary Key
Col1
Col2
Col3
Col4
Col5
```

Which way I should go? I care about performance. These additional cols are **tinyint** and will be default 0 not null.

SQL server 2008 R2

Comment: Really depends on the usage scenarios! Denormalising fanatics will tell you one thing, but for maintenance, code reuse, performance or usability you may need something else. Do you have a standard business object which maps to Col1-5, needing you to return all columns? Do you have lots of inserts, updates, reads

Comment: The col 4 and col 5 read update are very rare. though col 1 2 3 reads are too many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what your existing fields are. And also, there isn't a datatype called 'tinyBit'.

Even so, there are two possible impact cases:

1) Your table includes a bit column already and you are adding two bit columns

In this case, because bits are stored in packed bytes, the performance difference would be negligible anyway.

2) Your table doesn't include a bit column, or you are adding tinyint columns

In this case, performance would be impacted - as there would be extra information per row. However, 2,000,000 records isn't huge at all. A simple way to negate the cost of storing the extra columns in the same row would be to add an index which used `INCLUDE` to include the Col1, Col2 and Col3 columns. In that case, it would be usual for the Query Optimizer (QO) to select an index seek on the index with the included columns rather than a clustered index seek because it would have less cost.

Edit -> Given your clarification, case 2) applies, and creating an index with the relevant columns INCLUDED would likely increase performance over any existing clustered seek. There will be an insert cost - so it would be down to the table's read/write balance as to whether it was worth it.

Comment: sorry my bad it is tinyint . I dont understand what you mean here "Your table includes a bit column already and you are adding two bit columns" ? what do you mean includes bit column already ? if i have other bit columns what difference does it make ? and these new columns are not related to the rest of the columns expect primary key.

Comment: If you have 3 bit columns in a row, then those bits are stored in 3 bits of one byte. You could add another 5 bit columns without requiring any more per-row storage at all. Therefore, if you were adding bit columns, and you already had a bit column present, then it wouldn't affect performance at all really.

Comment: thanks now it makes sense. yes i already have tinyint columns :D but they are not bit column. so i suppose it makes difference.

Comment: @Matt Whitfield, do the bit columns need to be contiguous for them to be stored in the same byte?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG - is there anything about your question that I haven't addressed?

Answer (score 1):

For only 2M rows it is safe to say you should just keep it in a single table.

MS SQL Server stores NULL values efficiently (as little as a *single bit* under ideal circumstances), so you'll need many columns and very specific NULL distribution to see any storage savings at all.

Normally, vertical partitioning is done for better caching locality, but 2M rows will typically fit in memory anyway these days, so I doubt you'll be able to see any difference there either. You will see a (negative) difference because of the JOIN, though.

In any case, don't do anything blindly. **Measure** on realistic amounts of data with representative workloads and only make a decision after you know what the impact will be.

Comment: thanks for answer. what if i have 20 million rows ? because it keeps getting increased each day.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Even that is probably not a "lot" for modern hardware. But, to your greater point, if you keep increasing the amount of data, then the effects described in my answer become more and more pronounced and there is more and more need to measure whether better caching locality or JOIN will dominate in your particular workload. It's my hunch that JOIN will dominate, but the only one who can measure, and therefore know for sure, is you.